# creating own qml table view with all functionality

Tags: qt, qml

Does anybody knows how to create a table view using QML(Qt Quick 1.0)?

Tell me all ideas you have, my ended, I'm writing on PySide so unfortunately  I can't use QtQuick 2

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirement, you can use one or combination of :

1. [Qml Grid view](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-positioners.html)
2. [Combination of Qml  Row and Column](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-positioners.html)
3. [List View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-listview.html)